# What is the equivalent ASP.NET Web API Message handler for the ASP.NET MVC pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

ASP.NET Web API has a very useful asynchronous message handler in the form of
`System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler`.

I'm looking for the equivalent of such a handler to ASP.NET MVC. Is there something like that?

Note: I'm aware of Action Filters in both MVC and WebAPI, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Isn't [OWIN](http://owin.org/) tackling this kind of thing? (BTW, I believe a global [filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) is going to be your only option in normal MVC)

Comment: System.Web.IHttpHandler is the closest equivalent

Comment: @DarrelMiller: that doesn't touch the upstream though. At least an action filter gets pre/post request/response.

Comment: You'll want a `System.Web.IHttpModule`, where in `Init()` you can subscribe to the `HttpApplication`'s events.

Comment: Thanks all - I am indeed interested in access to both the request and the response objects. Furthermore, I need to share state between code accessing the request and the code accessing the response. (ActionFilter falls short here as state in the filter is not safe to share between the two overrides). Will look into IHttpModule angle.